# 'No such entity' error when saving category as anchor

Tags: magento2.2

I have a weird issue in that when I try to save a category as an acher is fails with a 'No such entity' error. Underneath the error there is a futher error of

> Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php on line 102

When I look in my exception.log file I see

> [2017-10-12 19:48:45] main.CRITICAL: No such entity. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity. at /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php:102)"} []

and in the system.log file

```
    [2017-10-12 19:48:45] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: No such entity.
Trace: #0 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(204): Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository->getById('2')
#1 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php(793): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getWebsite('2')
#2 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/ProductScopeRewriteGenerator.php(133): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->getStoreIds()
#3 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/CategoryProductUrlPathGenerator.php(54): Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductScopeRewriteGenerator->generateForGlobalScope(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), '384')
#4 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Observer/UrlRewriteHandler.php(192): Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryProductUrlPathGenerator->generate(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), '384')
#5 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Observer/UrlRewriteHandler.php(149): Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\UrlRewriteHandler->getCategoryProductsUrlRewrites(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor), 0, true, '384')
#6 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Observer/CategoryProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver.php(94): Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\UrlRewriteHandler->generateProductUrlRewrites(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#7 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\CategoryProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#8 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\CategoryProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#9 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#10 /var/www/mydomain.com/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('catalog_categor...', Array)
#11 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(818): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('catalog_categor...', Array)
#12 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category.php(1082): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->afterSave()
#13 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/AfterEntitySave.php(34): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category->afterSave()
#14 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#15 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#16 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#17 /var/www/mydomain.com/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#18 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(52): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#19 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php(110): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save_after', Array)
#20 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(96): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor), Array)
#21 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php(1053): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#22 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#23 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#24 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Category.php(43): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#25 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Category.php(29): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#26 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#27 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/FlushCacheByTags.php(68): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#28 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#29 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#30 /var/www/mydomain.com/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, NULL)
#31 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(647): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#32 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#33 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#34 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#35 /var/www/mydomain.com/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#36 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Save.php(215): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->save()
#37 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save->execute()
#38 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(229): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#41 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /var/www/mydomain.com/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Save/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#45 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#48 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /var/www/mydomain.com/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#50 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 /var/www/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#52 /var/www/mydomain.com/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#53 {main} [] []
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what's going on? I believe it may to do with our multisite setup but am unsure, store info is

```
+----------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| store_id | code    | website_id | group_id | name    | sort_order | is_active |
+----------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
|        0 | admin   |          0 |        0 | Admin   |          0 |         1 |
|        1 | default |          1 |        1 | English |          0 |         1 |
|        3 | irish   |          3 |        3 | English |          0 |         1 |
|        4 | pl_pl   |          4 |        4 | Polish  |          5 |         1 |
|        5 | de_de   |          5 |        5 | German  |          0 |         1 |
|        6 | fr_fr   |          6 |        6 | French  |          0 |         1 |
|        7 | de_at   |          7 |        7 | German  |          0 |         1 |
|        8 | fr_be   |          8 |        8 | French  |          0 |         1 |
|        9 | nl_en   |          9 |        9 | English |          0 |         1 |
+----------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Looking at eav_entity_store though it looks like it may have something to do with this?

```
+-----------------+----------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+
| entity_store_id | entity_type_id | store_id | increment_prefix | increment_last_id |
+-----------------+----------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+
|               1 |              5 |        2 | 1                | 1201584183        |
|               2 |              6 |        2 | 1                | 12301583211       |
|               3 |              8 |        2 | 1                | 13401580560       |
|               4 |              7 |        2 | 1                | 14401564687       |
|               5 |              5 |        0 | 2                | 200000001         |
|               6 |              5 |        3 | IRL              | IRL35301569424    |
|               7 |              6 |        3 | 353              | 35301569416       |
|               8 |              8 |        3 | 15               | 1535301569411     |
|               9 |              5 |        4 | PL               | PL48342658808     |
|              10 |              6 |        4 | 18               | 1848342658795     |
|              11 |              8 |        4 | 18               | 1848342658790     |
|              12 |              5 |        6 | FR               | FR33153264939     |
|              13 |              5 |        5 | DE               | DE49248574351     |
|              14 |              5 |        8 | BE               | BE32475983532     |
|              15 |              5 |        7 | AT               | AT43536957446     |
|              16 |              5 |        9 | NL               | NL31658957439     |
|              17 |              6 |        9 | 23               | 2300000016        |
|              18 |              8 |        9 | 23               | 2300000013        |
|              19 |              6 |        5 | 19               | 1900000086        |
|              20 |              6 |        6 | 20               | 2000000062        |
|              21 |              8 |        5 | 19               | 1900000079        |
|              22 |              8 |        6 | 20               | 2000000058        |
|              23 |              6 |        7 | 21               | 2100000008        |
|              24 |              8 |        7 | 21               | 2100000008        |
|              25 |              6 |        8 | 22               | 2200000010        |
|              26 |              8 |        8 | 22               | 2200000009        |
+-----------------+----------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Did you find out what was going on?